# What are the html rendering differences between IE 7 and IE 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

What are the html rendering differences between IE 7 and IE 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have some links regarding CSS support across IE's three latest versions.

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/
- http://www.evotech.net/blog/2009/02/css-browser-support/

Answer (score 2):

A big noteable difference is [IE8 is Acid2 compliant](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2007/12/19/internet-explorer-8-and-acid2-a-milestone.aspx), IE7 isn't.